# Is an elementary abelian group a non-degenerate symplectic vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A$ be an elementary abelian group with $|A|=p^{n}$, where $p$ is a prime number and $n$ is even. It is well-known that we can consider $A$ as a vector space of dimension $n$ over the field $F_p \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Considering the above vector space structure for $A$, can we say $A$ is a non-degenerate symplectic space? Is there any non-degenerate skew-symmetric bilinear form over $A$?

Comment: I've tried the bilinear form $f: A \times A \rightarrow Z_p$ with $f(a, b)= \prod_{i} a_i (b_i^{-1})$ where $a=(a_1,..., a_{2n})$ and $b=(b_1,..., b_{2n})$ in which $a_i, b_j \in Z_p$. But I'm not sure if it works since $f(a, a)=1 \neq 0 \in Z_p$.

Comment: That is not a bilinear form.

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: You're right. I found a bilinear form with expected features which is mentioned in answers part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the idea of [azimut](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/61691/azimut) in response to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323470/non-degenerate-bilinear-form-on-mathbbz-2-vector-space?rq=1) we can consider the bilinear form
$\\\hspace{6cm} f : \mathbb{Z}_p^n\times\mathbb{Z}_p^n\to \mathbb{Z}_p$,$\\\quad ((x_1,\ldots,x_n),(y_1,\ldots,y_n)) \mapsto (x_1y_2 - x_2 y_1) + (x_3 y_4 - x_4 y_3) + \ldots + (x_{n-1} y_n - x_n y_{n-1})$

which is non-degenerate, skew-symmetric bilinear form over $A \cong \mathbb{Z}_p^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look for simplicity at the case $n = 2$. Consider a basis $a, b$ of $A$, and defined the pairing to be
$$
\omega(xa + yb, za + wb) = xw - yz
$$
Then it is not too hard to show that this is an alternating form on $V$. It is also non-degenerate. Furthermore, it can be represented by the matrix
$$
\omega = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
From here it should hopefully not be too hard to see how you can extend this idea...

Comment: thank you for your response. I think I've found the answer!